# Why not getting any output in dplyr?

Tags: r

I cannot get any output running the following code and your help is appreciated.  The out column should be populated with the right values.

The function seems to work.  When I tried this below, I got the right output.

```
as.integer(floor((interval(d[3,2], d[3,3]) /duration(num = 1, units = "years"))))
```

The code that does not work:

```
 d <- data.frame(id = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"),
                d1 = c("1950-05-01", "1960-06-01", "1970-07-01", "1980-08-01"),
                d2 = c("2016-01-15", "2016-04-15", "2016-07-15", "2016-07-30"))


 calc_diff <- function(d1 = "d1", d2 = "d2")
 {
 dat <- tibble(d1,d2)
 dat <- as.Date(unlist(dat), origin="1970-01-01" , format="%Y-%m-%d")
 names(dat) <- c('d1', 'd2')
 for (i in 2:nrow(d)) {
    dif[i] = as.integer(floor((interval(dat['d1'], dat['d2']) /duration(num = 1, units = "years"))) )
    return(dif[i])
                        }
 }

 d %>% select(d1,d2) %>% mutate(out=calc_diff(.))
```

Expect a data frame output where the out column is populated with these values:  65, 55, 46, 36

Comment: The fucntion returns after the first time through the `for` loop. Move the return to the last function line, `return(dif)`. Without the indexing bit, `[i]`.

Comment: When I did what I suggested above, I got `Error in calc_diff(.) : object 'dif' not found`

Comment: You don't need a for loop at all. If you use `rowwise` before `mutate`  then the mutate runs on each row individually. And think about what you are giving as arguments, the way it is the first argument (`d1` is given the entire data.frame while the second argument is the string `"d2". You can give mutate column names directly (see`?mutate` for examples)

Comment: @rui thanks for your great suggestions. My code did overcomplicate things.  Yours work great.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question is complicating what can be vectorized.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

calc_diff <- function(DF){
  DF[] <- lapply(DF, as.Date)
  dur <- duration(num = 1, units = "years")
  intv <- interval(DF[[1]], DF[[2]])
  floor(intv/dur)
}

d %>% select(d1, d2) %>% mutate(out = calc_diff(.))
#          d1         d2 out
#1 1950-05-01 2016-01-15  65
#2 1960-06-01 2016-04-15  55
#3 1970-07-01 2016-07-15  46
#4 1980-08-01 2016-07-30  36
```

Comment: Or `d %>% transmute_at(vars(starts_with('d')), ymd) %>% mutate(out = floor(interval(d1, d2)/duration(num = 1, unit = "years")))`

Comment: @akrun This should be an answer. I was following the OP's code with a function and corrected it but this pipe is simpler.

Comment: Thanks to both @akrun and Rui for the suggestions.  They both work and really help.

Comment: It is mostly similar to your answer.  So, I will leave it there

Comment: @akrun  If d is a spark dataframe,  the above code will not work as expected, right? Is there a easy change to make the above code work in sparkly r?  Thanks.